# Moving site from doman to subdomain without breaking the links already shared

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I recently need to move my wordpress lifestyle site from main domain (http://secretdiarybd.com) to a subdomain (http://bn.secretdiarybd.com) . Currently i have about 8000 blog posts and most of them have been shared in social network sites (facebook fan page and twitter). If i move the site to subdomain then existing links shared in the fan page will be broken. Is there any way to redirect all those to subdomain by post id or something? Such that if post id is less than 8000 then it will redirect to subdomain otherwise go to main domain. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please follow the instruction : https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

You might set a forward from the subdomain to the folder of you're Wordpress? Don't know if it works but it might be.

Comment: I have to move from main domain to subdomain. Another wordpress installation will be there in the main domain. and existing site will be in the subdomain. How do i forward then? Forwarding also make the new site forward also.

Comment: Then you just have to follow the instruction what @Rahul Saxena  mentioned :)

Comment: His reference is just  moving the site to subdmain. But i need to redirect all existing links that already shared in social sites to the subdomain and the new site at the main domain should not be redirected.

Comment: Well, You can actually do something like it. But then you will have to write a  plugin for the way you want. This will only took some time but I don't see another way to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a tool like Updraft Plus, which does Replacement of URLs and Links on Migrations, really helpfull.

Other Idea is to just to a full table search via SQL in wp_options, wp_posts and wp_postmeta to find all occurences of http://www.oldurl.com and replace it width http://subdomain.newurl.com. But this is hideous, complicated and really, really not quite predictable.